# The fast way to execute rest requests that require incremented value (nonce)

Tags: rest, api

I'm working with Rest Api that requires an incremented parameter to be sent with each request. I use unix miliseconds as nonce and originally naively sent requests one after another but even if I send one message before another, they can arrive in a reversed order which results in an error.

One solution could be sending the next request only after the previous one got back. But it would be too slow. I'm thinking about less strict solution like measuring latency over the last 10 requests and waiting for x% of latency before sending the next message. I feel like this problem should've been already solved but can't find any good reference. Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Wrong design. Either you are using stateful requests, and then you need to wait for the previous reply before making the next one, or not. BTW, the nonce could be (and probably should be) more random (e.g. UUID like)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I agree it's wrong design but I'm talking to a third-party service and there's nothing I can change about it

Comment: Why do you absolutely need to send an *incremented* parameter? Can't you send some *unique* one?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I'm working with this api: https://poloniex.com/support/api/

Comment: That should go into the question. Don't comment your own question, but edit it to improve it